# About parabolic subgroup of a Weyl group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, root-systems, coxeter-groups, weyl-group

Let $W$ be a Weyl group/Coxeter group. Let $\Phi$ be the associated root system, fix a positive root system $\Phi^+$ and let
$\Delta$ be the set of simple roots.

Let $W_I$ be the parabolic subgroup of $W$ generated by $I\subseteq \Delta$.

1. Does $W_I=W_J\implies I=J$?
2. Does $s\in W$ with $s\neq 1$, $s^2=1\implies s=s_\alpha$ for some root $\alpha$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What properties of Weyl groups do you know which might help? Also, in question 2 I assume you want to exclude the trivial counterexample $s=id$.

Comment: My thought is that if 2. is correct. Then I can say the set of order 2 elements in $W_I$ is the set of order 2 elements in $W_J$. Then $\{s_\alpha:\alpha\in\Phi_I\}=\{s_\alpha:\alpha\in\Phi_J\}$. This implies $\Phi_I=\Phi_J$ and then $I=J$.

Comment: $s=-id$ is an element of the Weyl group for many root systems (e.g. all of type $B_n, C_n$, and all exceptional ones except $E_6$), and is a counterexample to 2. as soon as the rank is $\ge 2$.

Comment: 1. is true: the parabolic subgroups are in bijection with subsets of $\Delta$.